# Should I place SPA and RESTful API in different servers?

Tags: rest, oauth, single-page-application, restful-authentication

I'm developing a Single Page Application (SPA) and a RESTful API to serve resources to it.

Since I'm going to develop mobile applications, and even open the service to third parties in the future I thought of placing the SPA in one server and the REST API in other. I think that way I should be able to scale the service easily.

Should I create the web app (SPA+Resource server) in one place, or separate server is the right way to go?
Should I use some token protocol to authenticate the SPA to the REST API to guarantee its authenticity?

I read about OAuth, but it is very complex, and I don't no if it makes sense to my case, since I'm developing both ends. But it does guarantee the authenticity of the app (my SPA) and the user. Maybe OAuth is the solution?

Thanks a lot for any help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think that it seems to be a good idea to split the SPA and the RESTful service if you expect to have several consumers for it. The SPA will one. It will allow to prepare such structuring... I think that you should implement CORS in such use case. This following link could give some insights:

- **Understanding and using CORS** - https://templth.wordpress.com/2014/11/12/understanding-and-using-cors/
- **Debugging CORS** - http://restlet.com/blog/2016/09/27/how-to-fix-cors-problems/

Regarding token-based authentication, I think that this link could show how to implement such approach:

- **Implementing authentication with tokens for RESTful applications** - https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/implementing-authentication-with-tokens-for-restful-applications/

Comment: Guess I'm going to implement the SPA as a OAuth client, which will authenticate users with the REST API. Since the SPA is a trusted client I can get the user credentials directlye within the app...